# How can I test sending Ether to a contract with a `payable` receive function?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I've written Hardhat tests for a Solidity contract that contains a `receive() external payable { ... }` function.

How can I call it within the test with an Ether amount?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can make a transaction and send ether to the contract address

```js
const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

const transactionHash = await owner.sendTransaction({
  to: "contract address",
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"), // Sends exactly 1.0 ether
});
```

Making a transaction should call the receive function.

Comment: The BigNumber type from `ethers.utils.parseEther("1")` is an invalid type for the `params`. Using `toHexString()` also isn't working at the moment

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent that worked!

Comment: What method of the contract are you calling in the above answer?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```js
await contract.connect(account).receive({ value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1") })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround for this issue, based on Ether's version 6:

```
    import { ethers } from "hardhat";
    import { expect } from "chai";
    import { parseEther } from "ethers";
            
    it("Should be deployed and have a balance of 1000000000000000000.", async function () {
      const faucet = await ethers.deployContract("Faucet");
      await faucet.waitForDeployment();
        
      const deployedAddress = await faucet.getAddress();
      const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
        
      const tx = {
        to: deployedAddress,
        value: parseEther("1.0"),
      };
      await owner.sendTransaction(tx);
        
      const contractBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(deployedAddress);
      expect(contractBalance).to.equal(parseEther("1.0"));
    });
```